# How to select entire texts in class span

Tags: web-part, javascript, css, page-layout, html

I have an array title value with the class **.block .title h2 span**, I want to select entire texts in this class and check every title length. my script is

`x=$(".block .title h2 span").text()[i];
y=x.length;`

But it just displays the character of text. For example, when i=0, it displays the first character, when i=5, it displays the 5nd character.

How can I correct my code for display entire title  ?

```
<div class="block">
 <div class="title">
   <h2 style="padding-top: 18px;"> 
      <span id="title" style="color: yellow;">Welcome to this site</span>
   </h2>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by array title value? Do you mean to say you have multiple spans accessible the same way?

Comment: @uberz91 yes, mutiple spans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=$(".block .title h2 span#title").text();
```

If you have multiple spans then

```
var arrSpanTitles = [];
$(".block .title h2 span").each(function(){
    arrSpanTitles.push($(this).text());
});
```

`arrSpanTitle` will contain all span titles